# pointwise convergence on a.e. equivalent class is well defined

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Prove that if $f_n = g_n \ a.e$ for all $n$ and $f = g \ a.e.$ and we have $f_n \to f$ pointwise a.e on $E$.then $g_n \to g$ pointwise a.e. on $E$.

My attempt is:

Let $E_n = \{x:f_n(x)=g_n(x)\}$ and $A = \{x:f = g\}$, $B$ be the set that $f_n$ pointwise convergence.

we choose $x \in A\bigcap B \bigcap (\bigcap_nE_n)$,such that $g_n$ are pointwise convergence on it to $g$.
With $ (A\bigcap B \bigcap (\bigcap_nE_n))^c$
Measure zero.

I'm not sure whether my proof is right or not.

Comment: It is indeed correct.

Comment: thank you for your comment